# How to use log scale on polar axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I am trying to create a polar plot with a log scale on the radial axis but I keep getting an error. Some example code and the error are below. It seems to work fine in Cartesian coordinates, does anyone know what's happening??

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm

bazbins = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 360)
fbins = np.logspace(np.log10(0.05), np.log10(0.5), 101)
theta, r = np.meshgrid(bazbins, fbins) 

# Set up plot window
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9))#, subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))

# polar
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_rscale('log')

# carthesia
#ax.set_yscale('log')

# Plot data
#ax.pcolormesh(theta, r, r)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
ax.contourf(theta, r, r)
ax.set_ylim((0.0, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

Exception in Tkinter callback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1413, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 236, in resize
    self.show()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 239, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 421, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 898, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1997, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1045, in draw
    tick.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axis.py", line 239, in draw
    self.label1.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/text.py", line 591, in draw
    ismath=ismath)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 156, in draw_text
    return self.draw_mathtext(gc, x, y, s, prop, angle)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 145, in draw_mathtext
    x = int(x) + ox
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in matplotlib. You should not have to call the `set_rlim` (or `set_ylim`) method before `set_rscale` (or `set_yscale`). In addition, you must call `set_rlim` or `set_ylim` with the 0 or 0.0 as the lower limit.  Other values for the lower limit will also result in a crash. The problem occurs with other backends as well (I have confirmed the issue for the gtkagg and pdf backends).

I filed a bug report for this issue, which can be found [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1847). If this issue is affecting you, please go to the bug report page and leave a comment to let the matplotlib developers know that this issue is important to users.

Answer (score 14):

### Updated with `matplotlib v3.3.4`

- Update `def scatter_logpolar_mpl` to use `'symlog'`, because using `'log'` results in `posx and posy should be finite values`, and an empty plot for `'log-polar matplotlib'`.

```py
# updated function with symlog
def scatter_logpolar_mpl(ax, theta, r):
    ax.scatter(theta, r)
    ax.set_rlim(0)
    ax.set_rscale('symlog')
    ax.set_title('log-polar matplotlib')

# use other unchanged original functions

# setup the plot
r = np.arange(0, 3.0, 0.01) + 0.001

theta = 2 * np.pi * r

ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, subplot_kw=dict(polar=True), figsize=(12, 7))[1].flatten()
scatter_polar_mpl(ax[0], theta, r)
scatter_logpolar_mpl(ax[1], theta, r)
scatter_logpolar(ax[2], theta, r)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Original Answer

There are more problems with the current matplotlib and log-polar plots.

For example, try to add a small value to the radius in the [matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/polar_demo.html) for polar plots, and then use `set_rlim(0)` and `set_rscale('log')` to plot it (as has been suggested in the comments here). All values below 0.1 get some special treatment. This affects the ticks on the `r` axis (note the completely misplaced 10e-2 and 10e-3) as well as the plotted data:

[image: Examples of polar and log-polar plots]

The behavior seems to be undocumented. I ended up doing the log-transform manually (third plot in the series above). For others coming across this thread, here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def scatter_polar_mpl(ax, theta, r):
    ax.scatter(theta, r)
    ax.set_rlim(0)
    ax.set_title('polar matplotlib')
    
def scatter_logpolar_mpl(ax, theta, r):
    ax.scatter(theta, r)
    ax.set_rlim(0)
    ax.set_rscale('log')
    ax.set_title('log-polar matplotlib')
    
def scatter_logpolar(ax, theta, r_, bullseye=0.3, **kwargs):
    min10 = np.log10(np.min(r_))
    max10 = np.log10(np.max(r_))
    r = np.log10(r_) - min10 + bullseye
    ax.scatter(theta, r, **kwargs)
    l = np.arange(np.floor(min10), max10)
    ax.set_rticks(l - min10 + bullseye) 
    ax.set_yticklabels(["1e%d" % x for x in l])
    ax.set_rlim(0, max10 - min10 + bullseye)
    ax.set_title('log-polar manual')
    return ax
    
r = np.arange(0, 3.0, 0.01) + 0.001

theta = 2 * np.pi * r

ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, subplot_kw=dict(polar=True))[1].flatten()
scatter_polar_mpl(ax[0], theta, r)
scatter_logpolar_mpl(ax[1], theta, r)
scatter_logpolar(ax[2], theta, r)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

When I take out the comment in the line that sets up the plot window it runs for me.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm

bazbins = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 360)
fbins = np.logspace(np.log10(0.05), np.log10(0.5), 101)
theta, r = np.meshgrid(bazbins, fbins) 

# Set up plot window
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9), subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))

# polar
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_rscale('log')

plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
ax.contourf(theta, r, r)
ax.set_ylim((0.0, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I've tried `set_rscale` and `set_ylim` and no grid lines show up. Also a few of the very small coordinates (r ~ 0.02) aren't being plotted. Wonder if there was a bug introduced at some point?

Answer (score 0):

Set `rscale` after `set_ylim()`, like theta answered in the comments above.