# Define specific scales in matplotlib polar plot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm new in python. I have an array of data that I want to plot in a polar graph with matplotlib. I would like to plot all the data keeping a nice representation of each one, but the values scales are very different and the plot is not readable for each values... Is a scale for every 'prop' is possible ? (a specific scale for each angular value)

```
data=np.array([[0.35,2.93,8.02,12.79,16.59,19.46,21.63],[0.61,0.26,0.16, 0.12, 0.09, 0.08, 0.07],[0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.014, 0.013, 0.010, 0.017],[0.039, 0.013, 0.0066, 0.007, 0.0039, 4.3e-05, 4.9e-03],[7.1e-01, 4.3e-01, 2.7e-01, 2.0e-01, 1.6e-01, 1.4e-01, 1.3e-01],[3.5e-01,2.9e+00,8.0e+00,1.2e+01,1.6e+01,1.9e+01,2.1e+01]])

properties = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3', 'prop4', 'prop5']
axes = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
t = np.arange(0,2*np.pi,2*np.pi/len(properties))
a=np.append(t,0,axis=None)
plt.xticks(a, [])
for i in range(7):
    plt.plot(a,data[::,i])
plt.ylim(0,np.max(data))
plt.show()
```

I'm open to any other solutions as long as I can show all the data !
Thank you in advance

Comment: Using a different scale for different points inside the same plot seems a little contraditory to the concept of a plot with axes. Of course you could change the overall scale to be a logarithmic scale; but I'm not sure if this is what you want? Would you be able to show a picture of what your intended plot would look like? (You could even use paint or pen and paper or so to create that.)

Comment: There is a [question about log scales on polar plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919407/how-to-use-log-scale-on-polar-axis-in-matplotlib) in case this is what you are interested in.