# Set Log Scale on Matplotlib Radar Chart

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, logarithm, radar-chart

I was wondering how it would be possible to plot the following graph with a yscale that is logarithmic, due to the massive difference between numbers in the 'sample' list.

ax.set_yscale('log') seems to just cause errors.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,polar=True)

sample = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=13.3, size=(15,))
sample = [35.417256011315416, 0.028288543140028287, 1.3578500707213579, 3.3663366336633667, 0.8203677510608205, 35.445544554455445, 3.3946251768033946, 19.46251768033946, 0.7072135785007072]

N = len(sample) 

theta = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 2*np.pi/N) 
bars = ax.bar(theta, sample, width=0.4)
#ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xticks(theta)
ax.set_xticklabels(range(1, len(theta)+1))
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This question may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919407/how-to-use-log-scale-on-polar-axis-in-matplotlib

Comment: You could take the log of the data, then plot that on a linear scale. Same thing, you'll just have to relabel the axes appropriately :)

Comment: Thanks bnaecker, i'm afraid I wouldn't know how to do that.

Comment: Any help? I think i've got the 'sample' list in a logarithmically scaled array. How would i change the axes (presumably yticks)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ax.set_yscale('symlog', linthresh=0.01)` or `ax.set_rscale('symlog', linthresh=0.01)` (is the same in a polar plot) instead of `ax.set_yscale('log')`.

A day ago I uploaded a jupyter-notebook for more details at [GitHub](https://github.com/CorneliusKnappe/a-logarithmic-polar-plot-with-matplotlib).

[Your radar chart with symlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsuA6.png)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `np.log10` on the data is straightforward. But this generates ticks that are in this logarithmic domain. You can transform them back into the original domain of your data by inverting the logarithm, i.e., calling `10 ** i` where `i` is the new tick position. The key is that you're just updating the tick *label*. The tick itself is not moved.

The code below should do the trick:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)

sample = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=13.3, size=(15,))
sample = [
    35.417256011315416,
    0.028288543140028287,
    1.3578500707213579,
    3.3663366336633667,
    0.8203677510608205,
    35.445544554455445,
    3.3946251768033946,
    19.46251768033946,
    0.7072135785007072,
]

N = len(sample)

theta = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 2 * np.pi / N)
bars = ax.bar(theta, np.log10(sample), width=0.4)
ax.set_xticks(theta)
ax.set_xticklabels(range(1, len(theta) + 1))
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
precision = 2  # Change to your desired decimal precision
ax.set_yticklabels([str(round(10 ** x, precision)) for x in ax.get_yticks()])
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

This generates the following figure. Logarithmic data, with correct tick labels.

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you, this is perfect. Is there any way you could make the bottom of each bar reach down to the centre if its value is over 1.0?

Comment: You can do that, but it's a bit difficult. The problem is how the logarithm behaves near zero, where it diverges to negative infinity. You can shift the bars closer to the center, but you have to be sure to modify the _height_ appropriately, so that it ends at the same place as the _true_ data. Also, keep in mind that the new position is in the logarithmic domain. That is, moving the bar to -1.0 in this log-transformed space is really moving the bar to 0.1 in the original space. Look at `Rectangle.set_xy()` for details on how to move the bars, where you will be shifting the _y_ position.

Comment: bnaecker, thank yo ufor taking the time to inform me of these things.

Comment: You're welcome. These are fun problems, where you really see the power (and complexity) of `matplotlib`. Hope you can find a solution that works!

Comment: Thanks, yeah it was fixed in another question on here. To be honest, radar charts are a bit of a black box for me, fairly clear on most parts of matplotlib. It's a neat piece of software and i make all my graphs in it.