# Matplotlib: set_rscale('log') not working with polar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, polar-coordinates

I am trying to create a polar plot with log scale on radius axis basing on this [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_demo.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = np.arange(1, 2, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
ax.plot(theta, r)
ax.set_rlim((1,2))
ax.set_rscale('log')
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

but I am getting an error with a dozen of lines:

```
posx and posy should be finite values
...
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919407/how-to-use-log-scale-on-polar-axis-in-matplotlib) I should use set_rlim after set_rscale, but this swapping results in the same errors.

My matplolib version is 3.3.4.

Comment: Use this updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19082588/7758804) from the duplicate, which uses `ax.set_rscale('symlog')`.